# Connection Reset while reading large files and processing continuously

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection

I am making a REST call to download data. The proxy timeout of the server is 30s. THe data I download is huge (>2GB). The client box doesn't infrastructure to handle this. So I use a stream and parse the data then and there and store the manipulated data in my DB.

The problem here is since the proxy timeout is 30s when the client becomes slow the connection is reset by the proxy. When I directly hit the box I don't get any errors. Is there any way I can keep the connection alive even when I am not reading the stream from the server?

Answer (score 2):

Connections should only be kept open for as little time as possible. Hence, you should

- download the file as a whole
- write it to disk as a temp file (take a look at `java.io.File.createTempFile`)
- then read and process this temp file